# Pytorch bincount with gradient

Tags: pytorch, autograd

I am trying to get gradient from sum of some indexes of an array using bincount. However, pytorch does not implement the gradient. This can be implemented by a loop and torch.sum but it is too slow. Is it possible to do this efficiently in pytorch (maybe einsum or index_add)? Of course, we can loop over indexes and add one by one, however that would increase the computational graph size significantly and is very low performance.

```
import torch
from torch import autograd
import numpy as np
tt = lambda x, grad=True: torch.tensor(x, requires_grad=grad)    
inds = tt([1, 5, 7, 1], False).long()
y = tt(np.arange(4) + 0.1).float()
sum_y_section = torch.bincount(inds, y * y, minlength=8)
#sum_y_section = torch.sum(y * y)
grad = autograd.grad(sum_y_section, y, create_graph=True, allow_unused=False)
print("sum_y_section", sum_y_section)
print("grad", grad)
```

Comment: Have you tried implementing it with a slow loop implementation as you described?

Comment: I found a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use a new feature in Pytorch V1.11 called scatter_reduce.

```
bincount = lambda inds, arr: torch.scatter_reduce(arr, 0, inds, reduce="sum")
```

Comment: it would be nice if you could add a code snippet of the solution with `scatter_reduce` - for future readers of this answer...

Comment: Sure, I will add.

Answer (score 1):

I’d try to use a hook to manipulate the gradient in a custom way

Answer (score 1):

`torch.scatter_reduce` has a `src` positional argument in Pytorch 1.13.  This simple example demonstrates equivalence between `bincount` and `scatter_reduce`:

```py
num_bins = 8
bins = torch.zeros(num_bins)

#generate indices and weights
num_indices = 100
indices = torch.randint(num_bins, size=(num_indices,))
weights = torch.rand(num_indices)

# Counting Indices

# with torch.bincount
counts1 = torch.bincount(indices, minlength=num_bins)

# with torch.scatter_reduce
counts2 = bins.scatter_reduce(0, indices, torch.ones(num_indices), reduce = 'sum')
print(counts1)
print(counts2)

# Binning Weights

# with torch.bincount
binned_wts1 =  indices.bincount(weights, minlength=num_bins)

# with torch.scatter_reduce
binned_wts2 = bins.scatter_reduce(0, indices, weights, reduce='sum')

print(binned_wts1)
print(binned_wts2)
```